# How to make predicate to Entity's customized property

Tags: core-data, properties, entity, nspredicate

This question is an ongoing one for [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475856/how-to-group-fetched-result-from-core-data-ios-dev).

I want to make a predicate to filter the entity by my customized property, this is the entity class

```
@interface Expense : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * amount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * category;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * note;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * paidby;

//customized property
@property (readonly) int year;
@property (readonly) int month;
@property (readonly) NSString *yyyy_mmm;
@property (readonly) NSString *mm_yyyy;

@end
```

And this is my predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"yyyy_mmm == %@", header];
```

When run:

> error message NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath yyyy_mmm
>   not found in entity

This is not completely unexpected, I searched and find out it has something to do with key-value, listener stuff. But I do not know what to do exactly.

Any help will be so appreciated, and BTW the coding block has some problem, please forgive me.

Comment: The predicate for a (SQLite based) Core Data fetch request can only use *persistent* properties, no transient properties and no custom properties.

Comment: Simply, `yyyy_mmm` does not exist in your model as already stated by Martin.

Comment: @flexaddicted I would like to select all the expense with the specific year and month. Now I know what to do, I select and save all the data to NSArray and use predicate to filter the array, with expense model, that can use the property to filter. But I'm afraid it's not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Make any property you need to use in the predicate an actual key on the entity in your data model. If you can set the value directly, great, do that. If not you either want to implement `willSave` or use `KVO` and update your predicate key values from the other values in your entity.